# Is there a way to reassign multiple change requests within Visual Studio at one time?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs-workitem

I'm working in Visual Studio and I need to reassign more than fifty change requests to different people. Is it possible to reassign multiple CRs at one time and if so, is there a limit on the number that can be reassigned within one instance?

Comment: Do you need more information? If so, please update your question. If my answer solves your problem, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

There are two easy ways to do bulk updates:

1. [Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286627.aspx). Query all the work items you need in Visual Studio then in the work item query page select all work items and choose <kbd>Open in Excel</kbd> update the items in Excel and <kbd>Publish</kbd> them back to TFS.
2. [Web Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409280.aspx). The <kbd>Assign To...</kbd> in Web Access (or the <kbd>Edit Selected Work Items...</kbd> options from the Work item query results. Select the work items you want, right-click them and pick the option that applies.

You can also mass re-assign items using the Powershell cmdlets and the commandline tools from the [Team Foundation server power tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f):

```
tfpt Query /format:id "project1\Team Queries\My Work Items" | tfpt workitem
    /update @ /fields:"Assigned To=Jason"
```